# how to Enable filestream in SQL Server 2008 R2 using C# code

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, filestream

I have a setup file created for my wpf application which will install the .net framework 4 and sql server 2008R2 on a client machine.

However before running the sql script in my c# code I need to enable file stream in Microsoft SQL Sever 2008 R2/ Configuration tools on the my machine.

I need a way of doing it in c# code rather than doing it manually.

I have tried the following:

Enable FILESTREAM Feature Using Transact SQL (TSQL)

from page, http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1838 but it didnt work.

Thanks and Best Regards!

Comment: "didn't work" - did you literally get no error messages, no diagnostic information, and FILESTREAM remained disabled, or did you get some information you can share with us?

Comment: Hello, yes I didnt get any error message when I run USE master
Go
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options'
GO
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO but my file stream is still disabled

Answer (score 1):

1. Call this function.

   ```
   private void EnableFileStream(string instanceName)
   {
       //sql 2008 - ComputerManagement10, sql2012 - ComputerManagement11
       string SqlWmiPath = @"\\.\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10"; 

       string WqlSqlFs = "SELECT * FROM FileStreamSettings WHERE InstanceName='" + instanceName + "'";

       ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(SqlWmiPath);
       int arch = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? 64 : 32;
       scope.Options.Context.Add("__ProviderArchitecture", arch);
       scope.Connect();

       WqlObjectQuery wql = new WqlObjectQuery(WqlSqlFs);
       ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, wql);
       ManagementObjectCollection moColl = searcher.Get();

       foreach (ManagementObject m in moColl)
       {
           ManagementBaseObject param = m.GetMethodParameters("EnableFileStream");
           //0 - off
           //1 - enable transact sql
           //2 - enable transact sql and stream acess
           //3 - enable transact sql and stream acess and remote stream access
           param["AccessLevel"] = 1; 

           param["ShareName"] = instanceName;
           var output = m.InvokeMethod("EnableFileStream", param, null);
           if (output != null)
           {
               uint retValue = (uint)output.GetPropertyValue("ReturnValue");

               //analyze return value
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Restart system service corresponding to the **instanceName**. 
   If instanceName is **SQLEXPRESS**, then service name will be
   **MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS**. Restarting can be done by system console, or by another way.

   3.1 **sc stop "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"**

   3.2 Wait until it is stopped (check service state: **sc query "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"**)..

   3.3 **sc start "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"**

Answer (score 0):

Generally for any administration of SQL Server through .net code you should be looking at [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx). It may support enabling FILESTREAM at the DB level, but I'm not sure.

If it's of any help you are however at least able to create a new FILESTREAM enabled [FileGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895218.aspx) through the api. An example exists on that MSDN page, plus there are some blog samples out there if you google *smo filestream*.